# Proof that we can find rational numbers arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}$: direct approach.

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

The statement of the proposition:

> **Proposition**. For every rational number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a non-negative rational number $x$ such that $x^{2} < 2 < (x+\epsilon)^2$.

The most common approach to proving the proposition is by using contradiction ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253175/help-with-this-proof-numbers-arbitrarily-close-to-square-root-of-2),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233785/proof-for-epsilon-closeness-to-sqrt2-for-all-values-of-epsilon)).

My question is: is it possible to prove the proposition directly? More concretely, is it possible to find a function $f: \mathbb Q^+\rightarrow \mathbb Q^+$ such that for arbitrary positive rational $\epsilon$, we have

$$f(\epsilon)^2 < 2 < (f(\epsilon) + \epsilon)^2 $$

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f(\varepsilon)$ to be the truncation of $\sqrt{2}$ to $n$ decimal places, where $10^{-n} \leq \varepsilon$ is the nearest power of $10$ from below.

This ensures that $$f(\varepsilon) < \sqrt{2} < f(\varepsilon) + 10^{-n} \leq f(\varepsilon) + \varepsilon$$

To illustrate, if $\varepsilon=0.2$ then $n=1$ and the inequality reads
$$1.4 < \sqrt{2} < 1.5 \leq 1.6$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $$\epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt2}\epsilon\right\rfloor.$$ This rational is less than $\epsilon$ away from $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that [between any two real numbers there exists a rational number,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/421600/29156) given any rational $\varepsilon$ such that $4\sqrt{2}>\varepsilon>0, \exists x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x \in (\sqrt{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \sqrt{2})$, which gives: $x^2 < 2$ and $(x+\varepsilon)^2 > 2.$